# Bootstrap and collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

How can I use bootstrap dropdown with collection_select. This is my code

```
<%= collection_select(:item, :PriorityId, Priority.all, :PriorityId, :Priority, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'dropdown-menu'}) %>
```

But I want it to be a bootstrap dropdown instead of a plain html select

Answer (score 3):

Add the `form-control` class to your code:

```
<%= collection_select(:item, :PriorityId, Priority.all, :PriorityId, :Priority, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
```

`form-control` applies in both [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#selects) and [4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#form-controls).

Comment: Thanks. It looks better with this but not what's in the documentation, rounded edges, grey selection and shadow in the dropdown list. It uses button and ul see here - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: I'll accept as answer if no one gives better answer.

Comment: @HassanVoyeau you're saying it does *not* look like the example in the link you gave me above? Do you have any styles that maybe conflict with form-control... like in `scaffolds.css`

Comment: Oh, wait I just read your question and comments more closely... you should get rid of the class: `dropdown-menu`